# Meta Description says "Your browser does not currently recognize video format"

Tags: seo, google-search, meta-description

My site is indexed on google search but the description is "Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available. Click here to visit our frequently asked questions about HTML5 video."

Is there a way to get rid of this? I just want my other content to showup.

Comment: What video format are you using?

Comment: You say "meta description", but you only mean the description in the result snippet on Google Search, not your actual `meta`-`description` element, right?